# compare multiple set of rows in same table - bulk records efficient way needed-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table which has around 16 million records in it. THe table will be of the below structure.

```
id  col a    col b   col c  col d   col e   col f
1   A        b       c      d       e       f
1   x        y       z      xx      mm      kk
1   aa       bb      dd     cc      tt      ss
2   A        b       c      d       e       f
2   m        n       o      pp      q       r
2   aa       bb      dd     cc      tt      ss
3   A        b       c      d       e       f 
3   x        y       z      xx      mm      kk
3   aa       bb      dd     cc      tt      ss
4   A        b       c      d       e       f
4   x        y       z      xx      mm      kk
4   aa       bb      dd     cc      tt      ss
5   A        b       c      d       e       f
5   m        n       o      pp      q       r
5   aa       bb      dd     cc      tt      ss
```

In the above table if you compare the id fields of 1,3 4 all column values except the id will be the same. i need to group this together if all rows under the id 1 matches with all the row values of other columns in id 2 and 4.

so my end result should be i will be mapping 1,3 and 4 to a new common id say 'A' and id 2 and 5 to a new id 'B'. Please help me how to acheive this in a more performance effective way. 
its a large amount of data. I have already tried with cursor and except iterating through each id fields but it takes a lot of time. any help would be great.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you are doing this in a database, you should tag the question with "sql" and the database you are using.

Comment: hi Gordon, am using sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can do this by concatenating all the key values together, to form one mungo key.  These need to be in some order, and alphabetical order of the concatenated row values should do:

```
select distinct id,
       (select ',' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d + ',' + e + ',' + f
        from table t2
        where t2.id = t.id
        order by a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d + ',' + e + ',' + f
        for xml path ('')
       ) as mungokey
from table t;
```

You probably want some more reasonable key for this, so I would suggest `dense_rank()`:

```
select id, mungokey, dense_rank() over (order by mungokey) as betterkey
from (select distinct id,
             (select a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d + ',' + e + ',' + f
              from table t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ',' + d + ',' + e + ',' + f
              for xml path ('')
             ) as mungokey
      from table t
     ) t;
```